# JavaScript return object property value

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
{"Header":["Date","Test1","Test2","Test3","N/A","Test4","Test5"],
 "Values":[["Total Unique","79 280","1 598","5 972","20","2 633","9 696"],
           ["2017-06-19","28 026","1 036","3 667","20","1 097","4 672"]]}
```

My desired result is this:

```
Date
2017-06-19
```

What I was able to achieve:

```
Date ["2017-06-19","28 026","1 036","3 667","20","1 097","4 672"]
```

Using this code:

```
vm.header = data.Header[0];
vm.data1 = data.Values[1];
```

Comment: `data.Header[0] + " " + data.Values[1][0];`

Comment: If you just want the first go with the upper approach. However there may be a better solution based on your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Because data.Values is a two-dimensional array you can get the desired result by changing the code to:

```
vm.header = data.Header[0];
vm.data1 = data.Values[1][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Header[0] = 'Date';
    Header[1]= 'Test1';
    Header[2]= 'Test2';
    Header[3]= 'Test3';
    Header[4]= 'N/A';
    Header[5]= 'Test4';
    Header[6]= 'Test5';
    Values is 2D array
    Values[0] = ["Total Unique","79 280","1 598","5 972","20","2 633","9 696"]
    Values[1]=["2017-06-19","28 026","1 036","3 667","20","1 097","4 672"]
```

What you have tried so far is `data.Header[0]` would give you 'Date'. `data.Values[1]` would give you whole array. So you need to get "2017-06-19"  you have to get first element of that array ie `data.Values[1][0]`